# How to paste files from clipboard as file names in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Copying files in Finder and then pasting into editor used to result in one file name per line (file name only, not full path), regardless of the editor's current language mode.

Then an update notice mentioned introducing multiple options to paste either file names or paths. On my end, full paths are now always pasted, separated by space instead of newline, and with no popup showing up as promised, except in Markdown files where I do see the popup.

- This happens on two machines (settings synced) and also using an empty profile.
- Happens using the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command.
- Happens with workspace folder opened and with no folder opened.

```
Version: 1.80.0 (Universal)
Commit: 660393deaaa6d1996740ff4880f1bad43768c814
Date: 2023-07-04T13:39:33.766Z (1 wk ago)
Electron: 22.3.14
ElectronBuildId: 21893604
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 21.6.0
```

This is what I see when I paste:
[image: Text: "/Users/adam/Projects/test/file-2.png /Users/adam/Projects/test/file-1.png", no popup visible]

Comment: please show a screenshot of what you see when you paste. I get the relative paths pasted in a single line with a hovering menu button to change the paste mode.

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting). Don't delete the image though, since it's useful to see whether there's a paste formatting button.

Comment: are you pasting into files in a workspace folder? Or without an open workspace folder? when I paste in a workspace folder, I get the paste format popup in non-markdown files as well.